# How to specify directory for image uploader in install script

Tags: magento-1, image, image-upload, install-script

I have an install script that works, but doesn't upload the files where I want them:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'category_banner_image',  array(
    'type'     => 'varchar',
    'label'    => 'Category Banner Image',
    'input'    => 'image',
    'backend'  => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'nullable'          => true,
    'group'             => 'Category Promo'
));
```

It uploads everything to `/media/catalog/category` but I would like for them to go to `/media/categories/banners`.  How can I specify that in the install script?

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute code can not describe where to store image,
so you need to add this in your di.xml

```
    <virtualType name="vendor_name\module_name\BannerImageUpload" type="vendor_name\module_name\Model\ImageUploader">
           <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">categories/banners</argument>
           <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">categories/banner</argument>
           <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
               <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
               <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
               <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </virtualType>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused.  I only see di.xml files in my tests dir.  Google tells me this is a Magento 2.x thing?  I am using a 1.x version.  I tried dropping this in my module's etc dir, but to no avail.  Any suggestions for getting this to work in 1.x?